# merge the array of array in ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, merge

I have one array like below

`[["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]`

And I want result like below

`"GJ, MP, KL, HR, MH"`

First element of array `["GJ","MP"]`
Added is in the `answer_string = "GJ, MP"`
Now Find `MP` which is the last element of this array in the other where is should be first element like this `["MP","KL"]`
after this I have to add `KL` in to the `answer_string = "GJ, MP, KL"`

This is What I want as output

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  There is some reason why [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]].flatten.uniq isn't what is being asked, but I can't parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
ary = [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]
```

(where each element is in fact an edge in a simple graph that you need to traverse) your task can be solved in a quite straightforward way:

```rb
acc = ary.first.dup

ary.size.times do
  # Find an edge whose "from" value is equal to the latest "to" one
  next_edge = ary.find { |a, _| a == acc.last }
  acc << next_edge.last if next_edge
end

acc
#=> ["GJ", "MP", "KL", "HR", "MH"]
```

Bad thing here is its quadratic time (you search through the whole array on each iteration) that would hit you badly if the initial array is large enough. It would be faster to use some auxiliary data structure with the faster lookup (hash, for instance). Smth. like

```rb
head, *tail = ary
edges = tail.to_h

tail.reduce(head.dup) { |acc, (k, v)| acc << edges[acc.last] }
#=> ["GJ", "MP", "KL", "HR", "MH"]
```

(I'm not joining the resulting array into a string but this is kinda straightforward)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]
o = [] # List for output
c = d[0][0] # Save the current first object
loop do # Keep looping through until there are no matching pairs
 o.push(c) # Push the current first object to the output
 n = d.index { |a| a[0] == c } # Get the index of the first matched pair of the current `c`
 break if n == nil # If there are no found index, we've essentially gotten to the end of the graph
 c = d[n][1] # Update the current first object
end
puts o.join(',') # Join the results
```

Updated as the question was dramatically changed. Essentially, you navigating a graph.

Comment: Please read the Question again @dangarfield

Comment: Your edit contains more information that previously given. Can you demonstrate what you have tried so far? I see that you're a senior ruby developer

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- `a` is an `Array` or a `Hash`
- `a` is in the form provided in the Original Post
- For each element `b` in `a` `b[0]` is unique

First thing I would do is, if `a` is an `Array`, then convert `a` to `Hash` for faster easier lookup up (this is not technically necessary but it simplifies implementation and should increase performance)

```
a = [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]
a.to_h 
#=> {"GJ"=>"MP", "HR"=>"MH", "MP"=>"KL", "KL"=>"HR"}
```

**UPDATE**
If the path will always be from first to end of the chain and the elements are always a complete chain, then borrowing from [@KonstantinStrukov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008340/konstantin-strukov) [inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74462736/1978251): (If you prefer this option then please given him the credit ✔️)

```
a.to_h.then {|edges| edges.reduce { |acc,_| acc << edges[acc.last] }}.join(",")
#=> "GJ,MP,KL,HR,MH"
```

<sub>**Caveat**: If there are disconnected elements in the original this result will contain `nil` (represented as trailing commas). This could be solved with the addition of `Array#compact` but it will also cause unnecessary traversals for each disconnected element.</sub>

**ORIGINAL**
We can use a recursive method to lookup the path from a given key to the end of the path. Default key is `a[0][0]`

```
def navigate(h,from:h.keys.first)
    return unless h.key?(from)
    [from, *navigate(h,from:h[from]) || h[from]].join(",") 
end
```

Explanation:

- `navigation(h,from:h.keys.first)` - Hash to traverse and the starting point for traversal
- `return unless h.key?(key)` if the `Hash` does not contain the `from` key return `nil` (end of the chain)
- `[from, *navigate(h,from:h[from]) || h[from]].join(",")` - build a `Array` of `from` key and the recursive result of looking up the value for that `from` key if the recursion returns `nil` then append the last value. Then simply convert the `Array` to a `String` joining the elements with a comma.

Usage:

```
a = [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]].to_h
navigate(a) 
#=> "GJ,MP,KL,HR,MH"
navigate(a,from: "KL")
#=> "KL,HR,MH"
navigate(a,from: "X") 
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `arr.size.times` to loop

```
  def check arr
    new_arr = arr.first #new_arr = ["GJ","MP"]
    arr.delete_at(0) # remove the first of arr. arr = [["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]
    arr.size.times do
      find = arr.find {|e| e.first == new_arr.last}
      new_arr << find.last if find
    end
    new_arr.join(',')
  end

  array = [["GJ","MP"],["HR","MH"],["MP","KL"],["KL","HR"]]

  p check(array)

#=> "GJ,MP,KL,HR,MH"
```

Comment: This damages the original Array. Not sure if that was your intention

Comment: I think if the original array is no longer used elsewhere, else `arr.delete_at(0)` is wrong and I will remove this line.